# Get line number in file following TSQL error message

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sqlcmd

Consider the following sql script

```
:ON ERROR EXIT

PRINT 'Line 3'
GO

PRINT 'Line 6'
GO

SELECT * FROM NonExistingTable
GO

PRINT 'Line 12'
GO
```

When you run with SQLCMD

```
> sqlcmd -i MyScript.sql
Line 3
Line 6
Msg 208, Level 16, State 1, Server MyServer, Line 2
Invalid object name 'NonExistingTable'.
```

When you run in SQL Server Management Studio with SQLCMD Mode enabled you get

```
Line 3
Line 6
Msg 208, Level 16, State 1, Server MyServer, Line 2
Invalid object name 'NonExistingTable'.
** An error was encountered during execution of batch. Exiting.
```

But when you double click on the error line the query editor will jump to the problematic line.

Reported **Line 2** means a line number relative to the batch. Batches are separated by GO statement. We want to get a real **Line 9** answer.

I've also tried PowerShell's **Invoke-Sqlcmd** but it is even worse, since it does not detect such errors at all ([Error detection from Powershell Invoke-Sqlcmd not always working?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23471600/error-detection-from-powershell-invoke-sqlcmd-not-always-working)).

Is there a simple way to wrap our sql script with some helpers to get the desired real error lines?

**UPD**: I've changed the error script to make sure it would fail for sure...

Comment: What version of SQL Server are you using?  I'm using SQL 2014 ENT and I got the right line number, I even tried a SQL 2012 ENT db from SQL 2014 management studio, and that worked as well

Comment: Interesting. I am trying on SQL Server 2008 R2

Comment: I've got super wierdness:  If I connect to a SQL DEV 2012 machine from SQL Enterprise Mgr 2014 I don't get the error, if I do it from SQL Enterprise Mgr 2012 I do!  Why would Enterprise Manager be the difference?  (I triple checked that I was in SQLCMD mode.)

Comment: I've just checked on SQL DEV 2012, it is reporting the wrong line from both SSMS and from SQLCMD.exe.

Comment: If I use SQLCMD and connect to SQL 2014 ENT I get line 2.  So somehow SQL 2014 management studio is doing something different to get the right line number.

Comment: Perhaps you could keep track of the current batch in [Context_Info](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms180125.aspx) (which maintains its value across batches on a connection) and then use an error handler to output both your batch identification and SQL Server's line number. (The batch identification could be your line number for the first line in the batch.)

Comment: I can't find documentation on it, but IIRC this issue was fixed in SSMS 2014. The fix will not be back-ported to 2012 never mind 2008 or 2008 R2, and I don't think there will be any fix possible for `sqlcmd` either.

Comment: [There is a way of doing it if you can pre-process the script probably](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4054511/73226)

Comment: @MartinSmith, thanks for your idea, but it is not fully working, unfortunately. It is not enough space to explain it in the comment so I update my answer to address your idea

Comment: @mnaoumov - Thanks. Will be interested to see what the issues are.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is the solution I came up with: https://github.com/mnaoumov/Invoke-SqlcmdEx

And now

```
> .\Invoke-SqlcmdEx.ps1 -InputFile .\MyScript.sql
Line 3
Line 6
Msg 208, Level 16, State 1, Server MyServer, Script .\MyScript.ps1, Line 9
Invalid object name 'NonExistingTable'.

sqlcmd failed for script .\MyScript.ps1 with exit code 1
At C:\Dev\Invoke-SqlcmdEx\Invoke-SqlcmdEx.ps1:77 char:18
+             throw <<<<  "sqlcmd failed for script $InputFile with exit code $LASTEXITCODE"
    + CategoryInfo          : OperationStopped: (sqlcmd failed f...ith exit code 1:String) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : sqlcmd failed for script .\MyScript.ps1 with exit code 1
```

And it has a proper **Line 9** output

Just in case I inline the script here as well. The script may look like an overkill but it is written like that in order to fully support all SQLCMD script features and deal correctly with transactions

**Invoke-SqlcmdEx.ps1**

```
#requires -version 2.0

[CmdletBinding()]
param
(
    [string] $ServerInstance = ".",
    [string] $Database = "master",
    [string] $User,
    [string] $Password,

    [Parameter(Mandatory = $true)]
    [string] $InputFile
)

$script:ErrorActionPreference = "Stop"
Set-StrictMode -Version Latest
function PSScriptRoot { $MyInvocation.ScriptName | Split-Path }

trap { throw $Error[0] }

function Main
{
    if (-not (Get-Command -Name sqlcmd.exe -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue))
    {
        throw "sqlcmd.exe not found"
    }

    $scriptLines = Get-Content -Path $InputFile
    $extendedLines = @()

    $offset = 0
    foreach ($line in $scriptLines)
    {
        $offset++
        if ($line -match "^\s*GO\s*$")
        {
            $extendedLines += `
                @(
                    "GO",
                    "PRINT '~~~ Invoke-SqlcmdEx Helper - Offset $offset'"
                )
        }

        $extendedLines += $line
    }

    $tempFile = [System.IO.Path]::GetTempFileName()

    try
    {
        $extendedLines > $tempFile

        $sqlCmdArguments = Get-SqlCmdArguments

        $ErrorActionPreference = "Continue"
        $result = sqlcmd.exe $sqlCmdArguments -i $tempFile 2>&1
        $ErrorActionPreference = "Stop"

        $offset = 0
        $result | ForEach-Object -Process `
            {
                $line = "$_"
                if ($line -match "~~~ Invoke-SqlcmdEx Helper - Offset (?<Offset>\d+)")
                {
                    $offset = [int] $Matches.Offset
                }
                elseif (($_ -is [System.Management.Automation.ErrorRecord]) -and ($line -match "Line (?<ErrorLine>\d+)$"))
                {
                    $errorLine = [int] $Matches.ErrorLine
                    $realErrorLine = $offset + $errorLine
                    $line -replace "Line \d+$", "Script $InputFile, Line $realErrorLine"
                }
                else
                {
                    $line
                }
            }

        if ($LASTEXITCODE -ne 0)
        {
            throw "sqlcmd failed for script $InputFile with exit code $LASTEXITCODE"
        }
    }
    finally
    {
        Remove-Item -Path $tempFile -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
    }
}

function Get-SqlCmdArguments
{
    $sqlCmdArguments = `
        @(
            "-S",
            $ServerInstance,
            "-d",
            $Database,
            "-b",
            "-r",
            0
        )

    if ($User)
    {
        $sqlCmdArguments += `
            @(
                "-U",
                $User,
                "-P",
                $Password
            )
    }
    else
    {
        $sqlCmdArguments += "-E"
    }

    $sqlCmdArguments
}

Main
```

**UPD**: @MartinSmith provided a neat idea to use **LINENO** aproach.

Here is the version which uses this approach: https://github.com/mnaoumov/Invoke-SqlcmdEx/blob/LINENO/Invoke-SqlcmdEx.ps1 It basically inserts **LINENO [corresponding-line-number]** after each **GO** statement.

But if we consider the following script

```
IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.objects WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID('dbo.MyFunction') AND type = 'FN')
    EXEC sp_executesql N'CREATE FUNCTION dbo.MyFunction() RETURNS int AS BEGIN RETURN 0 END'
GO
LINENO 3

ALTER FUNCTION dbo.MyFunction()
RETURNS int
AS
BEGIN
    RETURN 42
END
GO
```

It will fail with

```
> sqlcmd -i MyScript.sql
Msg 111, Level 15, State 1, Server MyServer, Line 5
'ALTER FUNCTION' must be the first statement in a query batch.
Msg 178, Level 15, State 1, Server MyServer, Line 9
A RETURN statement with a return value cannot be used in this context.
```

So **LINENO** approach won't work for the statements that have to be the first in a query batch. Here is the list of such statements: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175502.aspx: CREATE DEFAULT, CREATE FUNCTION, CREATE PROCEDURE, CREATE RULE, CREATE SCHEMA, CREATE TRIGGER, and CREATE VIEW. ALTER statements are not mentioned but I think the rule is applied for them as well

Comment: This was very useful, but as we had a very large SQL input file to debug (4,3 GB), the script struggled a bit to read the contents of it. For anyone else with the same scenario, split your .sql into smaller chunks.

Comment: It works well but the added PRINT statement messes with any @@ROWCOUNT used after GO.